# Transport phenomenon

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, diffusion

What is the difference between heat transfer coefficient and the thermal diffusion coefficient? What is the practical thinking of this? How would we define it practically? Like Imagining the both , I would love to know their physical meanings?

Comment: What does your textbook say as to the definitions of these two (fundamentally different) quantities?

Comment: They have used the heat transfer coefficient in the Fourier's law of heat flux and they have used thermal diffusion constant in the case of energy flux . Thats what where I got confused cause heat is also a form of energy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heat transfer coefficient is equal to the heat flux divided by the temperature difference driving force.  The thermal diffusion coefficient (aka thermal diffusivity) is equal to the thermal conductivity divided by the product of density and heat capacity, and is independent of the heat flux and temperature difference; it is a physical property of the material.

Comment: Hello sir , I saw your bio . Fortunately I'm also studying in the same field in which you are expertise . I'm in 2nd year chemical engineering undergraduate. Sir it would be very humble of you if I can know your email id through which I can contact you for doubts ,I loved the way you explained. Thank you sir

Comment: You can reach me in personal Conversations at PhysicsForums.com

Comment: Okay sir I will